# jqGrid - Default Add/Edit buttons - Processing Server Response

Tags: jqgrid

I am working on my first implementation of a [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php). I am using the standard add/edit buttons that appear in the navGrid but am having problems identifying how process the server response when I click Submit in the edit/add forms.

```
.navGrid("#product-codes-footer",{edit:true,add:true,del:false},
{afterShowForm:afterShowEdit}, {afterShowForm:afterShowAdd} );
```

Is there a standard callback or event parameter I am missing somewhere regarding this? Is there a way to define how `saveRow` is called or is there a default success/error callback method I can implement?

Any direction would be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There appears to be a couple event parameters that I failed to completely read and comprehend...

API --> http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#editgridrow

using the event parameters for afterSubmit and afterComplete allow me to process the server response and update the form.

--Dan

**EDIT**
Here is an example of the code used...

```
.navGrid(
        "#product-codes-footer",
        {edit:true,add:true,del:false}, 
        {
            afterShowForm:afterShowEdit, 
            afterSubmit:processAddEdit,
            beforeSubmit:validateData,
            closeAfterAdd: true,
            closeAfterEdit: true
        }, 
        {
            afterShowForm:afterShowAdd, 
            afterSubmit:processAddEdit,
            beforeSubmit:validateData,
            closeAfterAdd: true,
            closeAfterEdit: true
        } 
);
function afterShowEdit(formId) {

            //do stuff after the form is rendered
        }
        function afterShowAdd(formId) {

            //do stuff after the form is rendered
        }
        function processAddEdit(response, postdata) {
            var success = true;
            var message = ""
            var json = eval('(' + response.responseText + ')');
            if(json.errors) {
                success = false;
                for(i=0; i < json.errors.length; i++) {
                    message += json.errors[i] + '<br/>';
                }
            }
            var new_id = "1";
            return [success,message,new_id];
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways I have seen to do this:

```
 jQuery("#search_results").jqGrid({
        url: host,
        datatype: "xml", 
        mtype: "GET", // Handy to see the params passed.
        height: 200,
        width: 500,
...
...
etc
        gridComplete: function() {
          var ids = jQuery("#search_results").getDataIDs();
          if (ids.length Empty Result');
          }   
          else {
              $('#jqgrid_error').hide();
          }   
        },  
        loadError: function(xhr,st,err) {
          jQuery("#jqgrid_error").html("Type: "+  
                   st +"; Response: "+ xhr.status + " "+xhr.statusText+'');
     }   
     }).navGrid('#search_results_pager',
        {edit:true,add:false,del:false,search:true},
        {
          afterComplete:processed, // processed is a function you define
          closeAfterEdit: true,
          reloadAfterSubmit:true
        }   
     );
```

From the documentation:

**afterComplete**
*This event fires immediately after all actions and events are completed  
and the row is inserted or updated in the grid.*
*afterComplete(serverResponse, postdata, formid) where*

- response is the data returned from the server (if any)
- postdata an array, is the data sent to the server
- formid is the id of the form

**gridComplete**
*This fires after all the data is loaded into the grid and all other  
processes are complete.*

**loadError** xhr,st,err
*A function to be called if the request fails. The function gets passed  
three arguments: The XMLHttpRequest object (XHR), a string  
describing the type of error (st) that occurred and an optional  
exception object (err), if one occurred.*

There is a handy/helpful PDF documents (a little dated):
http://www.scribd.com/doc/17094846/jqGrid.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
navGrid('#gridpager',{view:true},{},{closeOnEscape:true},{afterSubmit:processAddEdit}); 
        $.jgrid.search={
        odata : ['equal', 'not equal', 'less', 'less or equal','greater','greater or equal', 'begins with','does not begin with','is in','is not in','ends with','does not end with','like','does not contain'],        
          sopt:['eq','ne','cn','bw','ew']
        }
```